# LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation always returns null

Tags: android, location-services

I am trying to write a simple Android activity that gets the current device location and displays it. Manifest and code are below. The call to  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation() always returns null.

I've tried this on multiple devices, verified that location services are enabled, made sure maps is running etc. There's not much to this app, so I'm hoping someone can point out my error.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mistersquawk.helloagain">
st

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Code:

```
package com.mistersquawk.helloagain;


import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    static private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = null;
    private TextView textView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //
        // Set up to display a string

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (textView == null) {
            textView = new TextView(this);
        }
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
        layout.addView(textView);

        //
        // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.

        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
     }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // We are now connected!
        Location mLastLocation;
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if(mLastLocation != null)
            textView.setText(mLastLocation.toString());
        else
            textView.setText("Null mLastLocation");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // We are not connected anymore!
    }

    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // We tried to connect but failed!
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected.  Last known location will only return a location if it has one.  If nothing else is using the location API, it won't.  Never rely on it returning a value.  Instead register for location updates if you need a location.